# Linked List implementation and manipulations in C

Tags: c, linked-list, memory-management

While trying to learn some more C, I decided to implement a linked list and perform a few operations on it.

The first thing I wanted to do was read from a .csv of numbers (ex: 1,2,3,...) and store the numbers in a Linked List.

Once I have the linked list, I want to reverse the linked list and then I want the user to be prompted with the number to remove from the linked list.

Upon receiving the value, the removal operation will search for the value within the linked list and remove it.

After removal, the contents of the linked list will be printed out.

Can somebody look at what I have and give me some pointers on what I did wrong and how I can make it better? One thing I am rather worried about is how I am handling memory allocation and what I am doing is causing any memory leaks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//Defining the linked list struct
typedef struct node{
    int data;
    struct node* next;
} LList;

//Method to print out the values in a linked list
void printList(LList * head){
    LList* current = head;
    while(current != NULL){
        printf("%d -> ",current->data);
        current = current->next;
    }
    printf(" NULL\n");
}

//Method to reverse a linked list
LList* reverse(LList * head,LList * reverseHead){
    LList * current = head;
    while(current != NULL){
        if(reverseHead == NULL){
            LList * temp = malloc(sizeof(LList));
            temp -> data = current -> data;
            temp -> next = NULL;
            current = current -> next;
            reverseHead = temp;
        }else{
            LList * temp = malloc(sizeof(LList));
            temp -> data = current -> data;
            current = current -> next;
            temp -> next = reverseHead;
            reverseHead = temp;
        }
    }
    return reverseHead;
}

//Method to remove an element from the list
LList* removeFromList(LList *head, int elem){
    LList * current = head->next;
    LList * prev = head;
    LList * modifiedList = head;
    while(current != NULL){
        if(head -> data == elem){
            head -> data = head -> next -> data;
            head -> next = head -> next -> next;
            return modifiedList;
        }
        else if(current-> data == elem){
            prev -> next = current -> next;
            return modifiedList;
        }else{
            prev = prev -> next;
            current = current -> next;
            }
        }

    printf("\nEntry %d not found\n",elem);
    return modifiedList;
}

void listRemoverRunner(LList * head){
    //While user doesn't enter q
    //Prompt for the element that needs to be removed
    //Call List removal that takes the current list and value and removes the
    //value from the List
   char buf[100];   
   printf("\nEnter list entry to delete(from the original list, not the reversed), exit by entering 'q'\n");

    while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) != NULL) {
        if (buf[0] == 'q') {
            break;
        }
        char *end;
        int listEntry  = (int) strtol(buf, &end, 0);
        printf("\nRemoving entry %d from the list\n",listEntry);
    removeFromList(head,listEntry);
    printf("\nList after removal of entry %d\n",listEntry);
    printList(head);
}
}
int main(){
    LList *head = NULL;
    LList *current = NULL;
    FILE * input;
    int digit;
    //head = malloc(sizeof(LList));
    //Read the input from the file
    input = fopen("input.txt","r");
    //For each integer read, store the value in the linked list
    if(input){
        while(fscanf(input,"%d,",&digit)!= EOF){
            //printf("The number is %d\n",digit);
            LList *temp = malloc(sizeof(LList));
            temp -> data = digit;
            if(head == NULL){
                //printf("Adding the digit %d to the list\n",digit);
                head = temp;
                current = head;
                temp = NULL;
                current -> next = NULL;
            }else{
                //printf("Adding the digit %d to the list\n",digit);
                current -> next = temp;
                current = temp;
                current -> next = NULL;
            }
        }
    }
    //Close the file
    fclose(input);
    //Print the values in the linked list
    printf("\nPrinting out the original linked list\n");
    printList(head);
    //Reverse the original linked list
    LList * reversedList = NULL;
    reversedList = reverse(head,reversedList);
    //Print the reversed linked list
    printf("\nPrinting out the reversed linked list\n");
    printList(reversedList);    
    listRemoverRunner(head);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have 5 Suggestions.

- No need to pass the **reverseHead** in `LList* reverse(LList * head,LList * reverseHead)` method

Change that to:

```
LList* reverse(LList * head)
```

- There is **memory leaks** in your code. When you are removing an entry from the linked list, you need to release the memory associated with that node.
- I won't prefer **multiple return statements** from a method
- There are a lot of **wild pointers** is your code. wild pointers are dangerous, so whenever you declare a pointer, initialize it (At-least initialize it with `NULL`)
- For the current purpose I don't think you need this statement `fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)`. Instead, you can use `gets(buf)`.

You can change your `removeFromList` method like:

```
LList* removeFromList(LList *head, int elem)
{
    LList * current      = head->next;
    LList * prev         = head;
    LList * modifiedList = head;
    LList * deleteNode   = NULL;
    int    flag          = 1;
    while((prev != NULL) && flag)
    {
        if(head -> data == elem)
        {
            if(head->next != NULL)
            {
                head -> data = head -> next -> data;
                deleteNode = head->next;
                head -> next = head -> next -> next;
            }
            else
            {
                deleteNode   = head;
                modifiedList = NULL;
            }
            flag = 0;
        }
        else if(current-> data == elem)
        {
            deleteNode = prev->next;
            prev -> next = deleteNode -> next;
            flag = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            prev = prev -> next;
        }
    }
    if (flag)
    {
        printf("\nEntry %d not found\n",elem);
    }
    free(deleteNode);
    deleteNode = NULL;
    return modifiedList;
}
```

And change the method calls like:

```
head = removeFromList(head,listEntry);
```